# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel since partner webservice upgraded using System.Net and client certificate authentication

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, client-certificates, system.net

We have an application that use to call a webservice secured by SSL client certificate. Our partner upgraded their gateway and since this upgrade we are not able to call their web service anymore.

Here is the c# code that used to work

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, p) => { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
    req.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(CertificatePath, Password));
    var byteContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    req.ContentLength = byteContent.Length;
    req.Proxy = new WebProxy("***PROXY-URL***");
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    using (var requestStream = req.GetRequestStream())//Exception here:
```

Here are the System.Net tracing:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering WebRequest::Create(***WEBSERVICEURL***)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering HttpWebRequest#16639474::HttpWebRequest(***WEBSERVICEURL***#100646014)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Exiting HttpWebRequest#16639474::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Exiting WebRequest::Create()     -> HttpWebRequest#16639474
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering ServicePoint#5620158::ServicePoint(***PROXYURL***)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating HttpWebRequest#16639474 with ServicePoint#5620158
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering HttpWebRequest#16639474::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating Connection#52579650 with HttpWebRequest#16639474
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering HttpWebRequest#3454809::HttpWebRequest(***PROXYURL***/#589308768)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Exiting HttpWebRequest#3454809::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering ServicePoint#31093287::ServicePoint(***PROXYURL***)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating HttpWebRequest#3454809 with ServicePoint#31093287
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering HttpWebRequest#3454809::GetResponse()
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating Connection#11404133 with HttpWebRequest#3454809
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Connection#11404133 - Created connection from ***MY-IP***:56660 to ***PROXY-IP***.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating HttpWebRequest#3454809 with ConnectStream#35528341
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] HttpWebRequest#3454809 - Request: CONNECT ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***:443 HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] ConnectStream#35528341 - Sending headers
{
Host: ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Connection#11404133 - Received status line: Version=1.1, StatusCode=200, StatusDescription=Connection established.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Connection#11404133 - Received headers
{

}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] ConnectStream#51319614::ConnectStream(Buffered -1 bytes.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating HttpWebRequest#3454809 with ConnectStream#51319614
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating HttpWebRequest#3454809 with HttpWebResponse#59223347
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Exiting HttpWebRequest#3454809::GetResponse()    -> HttpWebResponse#59223347
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Entering HttpWebResponse#59223347::GetResponseStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] ContentLength=-1
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5564] Exiting HttpWebResponse#59223347::GetResponseStream()    -> ConnectStream#51319614
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] TlsStream#63248075::.ctor(host=***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, #certs=1, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Tls12)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Associating HttpWebRequest#16639474 with ConnectStream#32361769
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] HttpWebRequest#16639474 - Request: POST /WebServiceTarification/v1/Calcul HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] ConnectStream#32361769 - Sending headers
{
Content-Type: application/json
Host: ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***
Content-Length: 686
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469::.ctor(hostname=***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, #clientCertificates=1, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Attempting to restart the session using the user-provided certificate: [Version]
  V1

[Subject]
  E=***WS-EMAIL***, CN=***MY-COMPANY***, OU=***SOME-WS-OU***, O=***SOME-WS-O***, L=Bruxelles, S=Bruxelles, C=BE
  Simple Name: ***MY-COMPANY***
  Email Name: ***WS-EMAIL***
  DNS Name: ***MY-COMPANY***

[Issuer]
  E=***WS-EMAIL***, CN=***SOME-WS-COMPANY-HOSTNAME***, OU=***SOME-WS-OU***, O=***SOME-WS-O***, L=Bruxelles, S=Bruxelles, C=BE
  Simple Name: ***SOME-WS-COMPANY-HOSTNAME***
  Email Name: ***WS-EMAIL***
  DNS Name: ***SOME-WS-COMPANY-HOSTNAME***

[Serial Number]
  ***SERIALNUMBER**

[Not Before]
  7/5/2016 11:39:44 AM

[Not After]
  7/3/2026 11:39:44 AM

[Thumbprint]
  ***THUMBPRINT**

[Signature Algorithm]
  sha512RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.13)

[Public Key]
  Algorithm: RSA
  Length: 2048
  Key Blob: ***KEYBLOB**
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Left with 1 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Trying to find a matching certificate in the certificate store.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Locating the private key for the certificate: 
***CERTIFICATE***
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord, UseStrongCrypto), m_ProtocolFlags=(Tls12Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=198, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=CredentialsNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - We have user-provided certificates. The server has not specified any issuers, so try all the certificates.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Selected certificate: 
***CERTIFICATE***
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Left with 1 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Trying to find a matching certificate in the certificate store.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Locating the private key for the certificate: 
***CERTIFICATE***
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] SecureChannel#22820469::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord, UseStrongCrypto), m_ProtocolFlags=(Tls12Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=189, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 105dc48:104e560, targetName = ***WEBSERVICE-HOST***, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
System.Net Error: 0 : [5564] Exception in HttpWebRequest#16639474:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [5564] Exception in HttpWebRequest#16639474::EndGetRequestStream - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```

I'm using .Net 4.6.2 on Windows Server 2012 but I can reproduce it with .Net Core 2.2

Based on what I could see in wireshark, it seems that the code does not send the client certificate anymore even if it is configured in the certificate store. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I managed to make it work by using TLS 1.1 instead of TLS 1.2.:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

But the question remains, why it does not work with TLS 1.2 and I have this error message:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [5564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the TLS version. When they upgraded their gateway they propably stopped supporting certain versions.

Comment: @Peter4499 I'm using Tls12 which should be recent enough. I've tried ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12  | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11; and SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault but I still have the same error. Which value should I use ?

Comment: Could you be missing [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2973337/sha512-is-disabled-in-windows-when-you-use-tls-1-2)? SHA512 is turned off for TLS 1.2 by default. Consider using SHA256 in your client certificate, because not all systems 'understand' SHA512.

Comment: @JessedeWit from what I understood the support of SHA512 is part of kb 2975331. I ran 'wmic qfe get hotfixid | find "KB2975331"' on my machine and it seems it is installed.

Comment: Does your certificate have an MD5 signature?  Is the `PrivateKey` property non-null?  Have you tried using `X509Store`?

Comment: I would bet for the SHA512 point.  Note that your partner should also support SHA512/TLS1.2 combination.  In the other hand, why SHA512?  Have you tried with SHA256/TLS1.2?

Comment: Some [more info about SHA512 vs SHA256](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165559/why-would-i-choose-sha-256-over-sha-512-for-a-ssl-tls-certificate)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround we put in place is to use a reverse proxy (nginx) to handle the Mutual TLS. So we have:

|service (.net 4.6.2)| -TLS-> |Nginx| -MTLS-> |other service|

I think the issue is more at the OS level (Windows 2012) which does not supports some ciphers algorithm.